# What happens if my character is killed?

Tags: battletech

I was the victim of an unfortunate headshot by an enemy Hunchback.  My otherwise uninjured main character was instantly killed.

I was surprised that the game did not instantly stop.  However, I decided to reload instead of fighting on.

What happens if your main character is killed?  Since he's is the commander of the lance, and his back story has an impact on dialog choices, is it possible to play after death?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in the barracks, check the green icon next to your characters rank. It says, that this pilot is your character, the commander, and cannot die. However they will still get injured and may have to spend a prolonged time in the medbay.

In the event, your commander would be killed normally, they just get put into the medbay with max injuries.